# Как убрать точку в списке <a href="#">Home

Tags: html, css

```
<ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Home</li>
                <li><a href="#"> About</li>
                <li><a href="#"> Work</li>
                <li><a href="#"> Contacts</li>  
 </ul>
```

Comment: В html: `<ul> <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> </ul>` в css: `ul {list-style-type: none;}`